# Ibm MobileFirst Linker error at compile time

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, ionic2

I'm developing an Hybrid Application with IBM MobileFirst Platform Fondation 8.0, Ionic2 and Cordova.
On iOS I found a problem at compilation time, the same problem happens also using the default mobile first ionic template and so I cannot to upload software on emulator.

This is my configuration:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.11
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.20
ios-deploy version: 1.8.6  
ios-sim version: 5.0.8  
OS: Mac OS X Yosemite 
Node Version: v4.4.3 
Xcode version: Xcode 6.4 Build version 6E35b
```

At compile time I obtain the follow link error:

1] Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

```
std::terminate()", referenced from:
___clang_call_terminate in IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid(ZipArchive.o)
___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from: 
 ___clang_call_terminate in IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid(ZipArchive.o) 
 ___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
```

[...]

On internet I found an advice to add in Xcode linker option: -lc++

2] Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
_crc32", referenced from:
    -[ZipArchive addFileToZip:newname:] in IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid(ZipArchive.o)
_deflate", referenced from:
     _zipWriteInFileInZip in IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid(zip.o) 
[...]

On internet I found an advice to add in Xcode linker option: -lc++

Resolved adding -lz into linker options.

3] duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:

```
Torna a Casa/Plugins/cordova-plugin-mfp/IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationJSONStore.framework/IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationJSONStore(JSONStoreValidator.o)
```

Torna a Casa/Plugins/cordova-plugin-mfp/IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationJSONStore.framework/IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationJSONStore(JSONStoreIndexer.o)

It can be resolved removing -ObjC but removing it Application crash with the follow error:

```
[__NSDictionaryM cordovaSettingForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f814d2081a0
```

Somewhere I found a suggest to add ENABLE_BITCODE = NO but it is already.

Thanks.
Daniele

Comment: Please note that IBM does not officially provide any "default Ionic template".

Comment: Also note that your Xcode version is old and that you should upgrade to Xcode 7 at minimum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not do any of those workarounds.

1. Upgrade your Xcode to **v7.0 at the very least**.
2. Then make sure you follow these basic steps to use MobileFirst in Ionic apps: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/07/19/integrating-mobilefirst-foundation-8-in-ionic-based-apps/